# Value assignment not working the way I expect

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am familiarizing myself with scikit learn. I was playing around with the following piece of code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = decomposition.PCA()
print(pca == decomposition.PCA())
```

So intuitively, I expect `True` to be returned but `False` is returned. What is the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call the constructor `decomposition.PCA()`, it returns a new object. Two objects of the same class are not the same most of the time (unless using singleton class etc.)

```py
pca1 = decomposition.PCA()
pca2 = decomposition.PCA() # creates a new object.
```

Comment: Is it a property of all the constructors or is there anything special about `decomposition.PCA()`?

Comment: All simple constructors create and return a new object. 

Some special ones such as a constructor of Singleton class returns the same object every time.